# Building url string in ERB file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, disqus, link-to

I want to show the disqus comment count per article in my index.html.erb. I need to generate the url string and pass it to link_to

So basically something like  url = article_path(article.id) + "/#disqus_thread"
 the html generated url string will be http://example.com/articles/21/#disqus_thread

Here's the code :

```
<% @article.each do |article| %>

  <% link_to article_path(article.id)'/#disqus_thread' %> <-- not working.

<% end %>
```

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

So first thing you need to know is that all url helpers eventually call url_for. You can find documentation of url for at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/RoutingUrlFor.html#method-i-url_for

Looking at this you will notice that there's `:anchor` option that allows you to specify anchor of url. So the correct "Rails way" to do what you need is:

```
<%= link_to article_path(article, anchor: 'disqus_thread') %>
```

One other thing you seem to have forgotten is to use `<%=` instead of `<%`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't concatenate the string, you need to use `+`:

```
link_to(article_path(article.id)+'/#disqus_thread')
```

Also, as @engineersmnky states, in erb, `<% %>` runs code without rendering the return value. To render the content, your tags need to be formatted as `<%= %>`

Comment: might want to also mention that `<%` should be `<%=` otherwise it won't `render`.

Comment: Ah, indeed, didn't catch that.

Comment: oh thanks. simple. I was overcomplicating with the options param in link_to

Answer (score -1):

You can just do this for clarity:

```
<%= link_to (article_path(article.id)+ "/#disqus_thread") %>
```

I'm not sure I understand this:

> I want to show the disqus comment count per article in my index.html.erb

Do you want the link to show like:

21 comments

and then the link path as I outlined?  If so, it be like:

```
<%= link_to article.comments.count, (article_path(article.id)+ "/#disqus_thread") %>
```